# Netlify deployed but page not showing

Tags: netlify

[image]

so basically its my first time deploying in netlify and it says deployed but when i visit the link

it says it can't be reached

[image]

i don't know how to fix this i search from google, FAQ and even in youtube but nothing works

Comment: Please describe what kind of project(technology) you deployed and what steps you followed for deployment.

Comment: i followed the instruction from scrimba course, the free javascript cource and there's a part there that we'll use netlify to deploy that project, and basically what we did is made a repository and imported it from github then they said dont put anything in the settings like build commands, what's there is just the owner and the branch to deploy which is main